# Plot function with x-axis in log-scale using ggplot

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I want to plot a function (result of using `drm()` from drc package) using ggplot2, with X-axis in log-scale.

I have a code like this:

```
 library(ggplot2)

 args = list(A = 4.224536e+04, B = 1.335570e+00, C = 5.992606e-01, D = 2.341207e+04)
 LP.4 = function(x, B, D, A, C) {D + (A-D)/(1+(x/C)^B)}
 dose = as.numeric(rev(c(100, 5, 2, 1, 0.5 , 0.25 , 0.1 , 0.05, 0.01, 0.0001)))
 predicted = lapply(dose, LP.4, args$B, args$D, args$A, args$C)  
 df = data.frame(cbind(as.numeric(dose), as.numeric(predicted)))

 ggplot(df, aes(x=X1, y=X2)) + 
 scale_x_log10() + 
 geom_point()
```

Which generate points and axis exactly I need.

I'm trying to plot function over this points using `stat_function()` like this:

```
 ggplot(data.frame(x=dose), aes(x)) + 
            scale_x_log10() + 
            stat_function(fun = LP.4, 
            args = list(A = 42245, B = 1.33, C = 0.599, D = 23412))
```

But I can't get the same result. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How about [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030596/passing-arguments-to-function-with-a-view-to-plotting-with-ggplot-stat-function)? It may help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems similar to the one resolved in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382032/ggplot2-scale-x-log10-destroys-doesnt-apply-for-function-plotted-via-stat-fun).   Using scale_x_log10, the base 10 log of x is taken and then passed to stat_function for evaluation.  Try something like the following:

```
LP.4mod <- function(x, ...) LP.4(10^x,... ) 
ggplot(data.frame(x=dose), aes(x)) + 
 scale_x_log10() + 
 stat_function(fun = LP.4mod, 
            args = list(A = 42245, B = 1.33, C = 0.599, D = 23412))
```