# Given a data frame of parameters, plot a univariate function with those parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data.frame with specific coefficients. For the purposes of MWE,

```
DF <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100))
```

I want to plot the equation `y = a*x + b` for each value of `a` and `b` over a specified interval of `x`. The function `stat_function` is close to what I want, but it doesn't seem to accept a function with varying parameters.

I appreciate I could just create a fine-enough sequence along the interval, then left join the data frame to the sequence, then use `mutate` to manually get a `y`. However, I'm curious whether there is a more direct method.

More generally, given a function `f(x; a1, a2, ..., an) : \R \to \R` with a data.frame of parameters, how can we ask ggplot to plot a line for each row of parameters over an interval in x?

Comment: I haven't tried out now (no access to R), but does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/21032286/2094622

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach:

```
linear_fun <- function(x, a, b) {
  a*x + b
}

stat_linear_fun <- function(x_range, a, b) 
  stat_function(data = data.frame(x = x_range), 
                mapping = aes(x),
                fun = linear_fun, 
                args = list(a = a, b = b))

plot_ab <- function(DF, x_range) {
  p <- ggplot()
  for (i in 1:nrow(DF)) {
    p <- p + stat_linear_fun(x_range, DF$a[i], DF$b[i])
  }
  p
}

DF <- data.frame(a = -2:2, b = c(0, -3, 2, -5, 6))
plot_ab(DF, c(0, 10))
```

[image]